Stop bind -x command output from overwriting current prompt string
I have the following two bash aliases defined in .bash_aliases:
# Better ls -al
bind -x '"\el":"command ls -lAtr"'

# Show newest 10 files in a folder
bind -x '"\eh":"command ls -1U | head"'

Now when I hit Alt+h or Alt+l to invoke the command, the command output overwrites the last shell prompt. This makes it hard to find where an ls starts and ends (if invoked multiple times). How can I stop it from doing that?

Side note: ls -U has nothing to do with "newest" or "oldest". What you get depends on the filesystem. In some filesystems the directory order may kinda allow you to get names of "newest files", but there is no guarantee; instead there are edge cases and surprises. You should use -t and related options.

@KamilMaciorowski True but on our servers sometimes ls is just painfully slow and I needed the fastest possible way to gauge the filename format in a folder of millions of files (following the same format). You're right thought that the comment doesn't make sense, so I'm going to change it. Thanks for pointing that out.


the command output overwrites the last shell prompt

Each of your bindings does not inject a string into the command line and "presses" Enter. It interprets and executes the string without typing it (kinda like when sourcing a script, when your interactive shell interprets lines of the script silently, i.e. without printing a prompt for each line and the line itself). In case of such binding the shell deliberately removes the old prompt and writes it anew after the output, along with what you have typed so far (which is a nice feature: you can use your bindings to get information while crafting a command).
Injecting a string into the command line is possible, but I think it's better to make the shell print a fake prompt. This is how you can do it:
bind -x '"\eh":printf "%s%s\n" "${PS1@P}" "command ls -1U | head"; command ls -1U | head'

Here printf "%s%s\n" "${PS1@P}" "command ls -1U | head" is responsible for printing a fake prompt (${PS1@P}) with a "typed" command (command ls -1U | head before the semicolon) that may or may not be equal to the actual command (after the semicolon).
Tested in Bash 5.2.15.

If you want Alt+h to act as if typing command ls -1U | head<Enter>, just do bind -s '"\eh":"command ls -1U | head\r"', no need for the READLINE_LINE of newer versions of bash.
